# Changing Node timezone over Azure

Tags: node.js, azure

Any idea how I can change default timezone in an Express Node app running on Azure?
I have way two ways with no results:

1) Adding WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE to application settings, with for example "AUS Eastern Standard Time" as value

2) Changing directly inside node app, www.ts, with for example "process.env.TZ="UTC+3"

Any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot get timezone to work by setting the TZ env variable when running both locally (Windows OS) and on Azure Web App.

However, if you can't do that, it should be possible to use [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) as a workaround.

**Install:**

```
npm install moment-timezone --save
```

**Use:**

```
var Moment = require('moment-timezone');
Moment().tz('Australia/Sydney').format();
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron but I dont want to do this each time I have to manage a date, looking for a simpler solution